# Cannot resolve ScalaTest from Gradle

Tags: scala, gradle, scalatest

I'm trying to run a simple ScalaTest class with gradle but I keep getting this log from gradle:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testCompile'.
> Could not download artifact 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3@jar'
   > Artifact 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3@jar' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

I have these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile "io.spray:spray-client:1.2.0"
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3"
    compile "org.scalatest:scalatest_2.10:1.9.1"
}
```

If I run the task with the `--stacktrace` option I get this:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testCompile'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDep
endencyResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDep
endencyResolver.access$000(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDep
endencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.getFiles(ErrorHandlingArtifac
tDependencyResolver.java:84)
```

Basically I'm using the default maven repositores:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 2.10.3 version of `scala-library` on Maven Central. The latest I see is `2.10.2-RC2`. That's likely the problem.

EDIT: 2.10.3 is available from Maven Central (I looked in the wrong place). Given the information you provided, I can't say what the problem is, but here is what I'd do:

1. To rule out a general networking problem, go to http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.3/ in your browser, and download the Jar manually.
2. Make sure you aren't behind a proxy, or configure Gradle accordingly if you are.
3. Remove declaration of `mavenLocal()`.
4. Run `gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies`.
5. Delete or rename `~/.gradle`, and try again.
6. If problem persists, run with `--info`, `--debug`, or `--stacktrace`, and look for hints.

PS: ScalaTest usually goes on the `testCompile` configuration.

PPS: `mavenLocal()` should only be declared when exchanging artifacts with local Maven builds. It won't save any downloading time or anything. Conversely, it will make the build slower and less repeatable.

Comment: 2.10.3 is the latest stable release of Scala.  It looks like it's on Maven Central to me: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.scala-lang|scala-library|2.10.3|jar

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I was mistakenly looking at `org.scala-lang.virtualized:scala-library`. Will edit my answer.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser [I had to run them as jUnit tests](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/etienne_practicalgradle_org-1fwpbv) but you gave me the answer in other place.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser also I was using the maven local because I had to test some libraries at work.